# Selenium Select Div By Class, no such element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use selenium to open a webpage and click an element (maximize screen button that's not really a button) to maximize the video. I've tried a few variations of finding element by xpath, but none have worked..  Here is my code below, the webpage is accessible.. I really just need the xpath/to know how this xpath should be formatted.. Appreciate any help !

```
import time 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='./driver/chromedriver')


DejeroControlVideo1 = "https://control.dejero.com/return_video/9I_HsFn7NYHiKvtJbHa3WQ"  

driver.get(DejeroControlVideo1)


#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

PreviewSwitch = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='ON']")
PreviewSwitch.click()
print("preview")


FullscreenButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " lh-solid ")]')[0]
FullscreenButton.click()
print("full screen")

time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPATH expression:

```
(//i[contains(@ng-hide,'isFullscreen || isFullWindow')])[1]
```

**Working code:** (Note: Have used `ExplicitWait` and removed `time.sleep()` )

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
DejeroControlVideo1 = "https://control.dejero.com/return_video/9I_HsFn7NYHiKvtJbHa3WQ"
driver.get(DejeroControlVideo1)
PreviewSwitch = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='ON']")
PreviewSwitch.click()
print("preview")
FullscreenButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//i[contains(@ng-hide,'isFullscreen || isFullWindow')])[1]")))
FullscreenButton.click()
print("full screen")
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

As fullscreen mode isn't a clickable button but when you hover over on selected raw html then it is selected. So it's possible to make full screen using selenium `ActionChains` class as follows:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
url = 'https://control.dejero.com/return_video/9I_HsFn7NYHiKvtJbHa3WQ'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

fullscreen_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.fr.lh-solid")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(fullscreen_button).click().perform()
time.sleep(2)

#driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I gave the check to Shawn since he replied first - but I like this one shows another way to do the same thing, those action chains will be useful. First time using Selenium for a small project!